# Enabling angularJS on static HTMLs using YEOMAN

Tags: angularjs, yeoman

I need help in using YEOMAN to enable Angular on static HTML. I have static HTML files which needs AngularJS to be enables. I need to understand is that possible to use YEOMAN on existing HTMLs to enable Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Got a resolution.You can implement angular on htmls and bower include all the dependencies.